# Does AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() frees a slot in the thread pool?

Tags: .net, multithreading, autoresetevent

I am trying to synchronize an asynchronous method. The main advantage of the async version is that it frees a slot in the thread pool. I would like to keep this advantage in my sync version. When I use AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() it is equivalent to a Thread.Sleep() in terms of thread pool usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `WaitOne` the current thread will block and wait for the event to be signaled. Just like with `Thread.Sleep` the thread will not be released to the thread pool. The difference is that with `Thread.Sleep` you need to specify a fixed time during which the current thread will be blocked, while `WaitOne` will block until some other thread calls `Set` or a timeout occurs.

Comment: It does not? I was sure it did.. =(